# What kind of JavaScript design pattern is this?

Tags: web-development, design-patterns, javascript, websites

In our workplace we use simple ajax library for getting page data and submitting changes to the server. Sometimes we need to change the form’s field values. We know that fields can be of any type (dropdown, textbox, radio buttons, etc.) and one of the most annoying and tedious tasks was remembering each field’s ID so could do the manipulation. (The task can exceed a few days, so I had to keep the IDs in a text document). So I made this design pattern for easily working with the fields.

```
 function FormFieldsManager() {
            var FormMgr = {
                txtGradeName: function (txt) {
                    if (txt) {
                        $('#txtGradeName').val(txt);
                    }
                    else {
                        return $('#txtGradeName').val();
                    }
                },
                txtGradeDesc: function (txt) {
                    if (txt) {
                        $('#txtGradeDesc').text(txt);
                    }
                    else {
                        return $('#txtGradeDesc').text();
                    }
                },
                ddStatus: function (txt) {
                    if (txt) {
                        if (isNaN(txt)) {
                            $("#ddStatus").val(txt);
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#ddStatus")[0].selectedIndex = txt;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return $('#ddStatus :selected').val();//selected value: A
                    }
                }
            };
        return FormMgr;
        };
```

To use this function, I just call the method and I could navigate the form fields and get full JavaScript intellisense.

```
var form = FormFieldsManager();
form.txtGradeName('Software Developer');//to set the field value
form.txtGradeName();//to get the field value
```

**So my questions are,**

1. What specific design pattern is this?
2. What suggestions for improvement can you give?

**P.S.:** I like to call it jsPageObject.

Comment: Most of the if checks are useless. `val` already does them.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Well I used if for checking if there is a value passed then set it to the field value else just return the field value ,I don't see them useless can you make a post and kindly point them out

Comment: Just do `return obj.val(txt)` and you have exactly the same behavior. `val()` does what your checks are doing. Same for `text()`.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine hmm,I never thought like that :), Well I don't wanna set empty string into text field that's one thing I have to take care of.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine There is a slight difference: `''` will clear the value with `.text()`, but is false so here it acts as a getter.  Might be the same with `.val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is superfluous since you will only need a once instance of that object ever because it has no state. You can simply do

```
var FormFieldsManager = {
    txtGradeName: function (txt) {
        ...
    },
    txtGradeDesc: function (txt) {
        ...
    },
    ddStatus: function (txt) {
        ...
    }
};
```

You can simply refer to that, no need to create it. This is simply namespacing static functions somewhere, dunno if that even has a name.

---

If it was an actual object with state, I guess an improvement would be to use prototype so it's not as cast in concrete as it is now. You also
won't create the function objects from scratch everytime but that only really matters when you create
100+ instances of something.

```
//This causes an error when you forgot to specify `new` as in `new FormFieldsManager()`
"use strict";

var method = FormFieldsManager.prototype;

function FormFieldsManager() {
    this.state = "something";
}

method.txtGradeName = function (txt) {
    ...
};

method.txtGradeDesc = function (txt) {
    ...
};

method.ddStatus = function (txt) {
    ...
};
```

Comment: hmm ,I agree with the `One Instance` tip. +1 for that

Comment: As a C# developer I see no benefit of using prototypes ,when I can still do what I want , the last snippet of your's can be written without prototype , why using prototype can be helpful, can you throw some light?

Comment: @dotNetSoldier because it's more extensible and flexible. Your function always returns a plain object that has no inheritance at all. It's the equivalent of using concrete final class in Java that doesn't even implement any interfaces, I dunno what's C# equivalent.

Comment: A comparison can help b/w your snippet and mine ,I'm reading on prototype now...

Comment: Also because there is still only one instance of the prototype.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine in the prototype code I am assuming multiple instances (because there is state too), the object literal is direct equivalent of the OP's code.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple instances, all using a single instance of the prototype. Thus, saving memory usage...

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, yeah :P

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Well guys do you really call it a design pattern ?

Comment: It could be called namespacing pattern or a singleton, does it matter? There are far worse problems with this such as implicitly storing state in the DOM.

Comment: @Esailija What are the worse problems ?,what do you see , I would like to know !

Comment: @dotNetSoldier well it's redundant because you are just replicating what jQuery already does, the client code can just directly call jQuery. Like Florian said, the checks are useless. OTOH if you provided useful functionality, you are storing state implicitly in the dom so the object is not in control of itself. `jQuery.val()` is not a simple `.value =`, especially for select elements it does all the stuff you already reimplemented.

Comment: Well don't you see ,I don't need to remember field id's (sometimes the page can have over 15 fields ), and the page gets filled `$` symbols all over sometimes particular fields needs a long jquery selector ,so I think I'm simplifying that and trying not to repeat jquery again and again.

Comment: @dotNetSoldier then just remember the field ids: http://pastebin.com/UTxaFkLr . :P You can call `FormMgr.ddStatus.val()` for example and it would do exactly the same as your function right now.

Comment: Hmmm..., Intersting ,Never thought like that :) ,thanks for that